# C: using sentinels on lists

Tags: c, list, sentinel

Hello so I am learning linked lists and I have to write several functions by using a sentinel. I have this definition: A sentinel is a fake element that is the first element of the list. An empty list is then a single sentinel and not a NULL pointer.

I need initialise the sentinel of an empty list

```
void list_init(struct list *list);
```

and check if the list is empty (return true is empty)

```
int list_is_empty(struct list *list);
```

but I am completely lost, could you help me out, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I cannot provide an example since it is not initalized :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linked list node always has a next member

```
struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list *next;
};
```

When you create your sentinel you initialize next to NULL

```
void list_init(struct list *list)
{
    list->data = -1;
    list->next = NULL;
}


struct list *head = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
list_init(head);
```

Now the head has a next member of NULL so all you have to do is check if next equals NULL

```
int list_is_empty(struct list *list)
{
    if (list->next == NULL) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

One you add one node head->next becomes NOT NULL and you will know the list is not empty. But you have to make sure that you always pass the head to the list_functions.

Comment: thank you very much, but can you explain me why you did 

    list->data = -1;

why set it to -1 ?

Comment: that was just a random value

Comment: but then, what if in the list i have other values of -1 how do we know which one is the sentinel ? what is the point of using a sentinel

Comment: the int is not the sentinel, the next pointer is. The int is just useless for the first node

Comment: i don't understand what actually is a "sentinel" ? it is a node ? what is its role

Comment: sentinel is a node with a special value which has no meaning to the program. Google "sentinel C"